# Can I label streams during import in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, script

Suppose I import three videos:

```
-i 'video0.mov'
-i 'video1.mov'
-i 'video2.mov'
```

Then I open a filter_complex. I can send the videos filters by referring to their number, which ffmpeg documentation calls "file_index": `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`.

This is fine, but suppose I come back later and remove everything related to video1.mov and the line that imports it. Now `[1]` refers to video3.mov and there is no `[2]` at all.

In the filtergraph I can apply a label by sending the video to a labeled output, ie:

```
[0] copy [video0]
```

but I have to be able to address the original file_index first.

I'm trying to do irritatingly complicated things with scripts, which include things like "import a png and overlay it, or not, based on a boolean setting". Once you have more than one import line that may or may not happen, labeling becomes an issue.

Is there any way to apply a label to an input at the time of import, so I never have to use file_index and won't break anything if the number or order of imports changes?

Comment: Not possible. Feel free to open an enhancement ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org. See 'Submitting a bug report'

Comment: @Gyan Will do, thank you.